# JQuery, send JSON object using GET method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send a json object using GET method. My code:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "/api/endpoint",
           type: "GET",
           data: {"sort":"date"},
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
           ...
```

However, the headers received have "Content-Length" set to zero, hence my json parser on the server doesn't read the content.

I have already tried setting content length header, but it still comes to the server as zero:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "/api/endpoint",
           headers: {"CONTENT_LENGTH",JSON.stringify({"sort":"date"}).length},
           type: "GET",
           data: {"sort":"date"},
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
           ...
```

Any idea how to get this working? It HAS to be GET request.

Comment: GET request have not content???

Comment: Content-length is irrelevant because you are not making a request with a body. How are you reading the request?

Comment: Have you checked how your request looks like (for example in Firebug - Net tab)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

GET requests ([at least usually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5216567/1048572)) do not have a message body. As mentioned in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), jQuery appends `data` of GET requests to the url parameters. You should be able to read your `sort` parameter from there with your server application.

BTW, no user agent will allow you to set the `Content-Length` header - it will (and must) be done automatically depending on the sent data.

Answer (score 22):

There are a few places where you have gone a bit wrong.

- It is not `CONTENT_LENGTH`, its `Content-Length`.
- Do not set `Content-Length` header, the browser will do it for you.
- Get request has content-length = 0.

Something like the below should work for you:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/endpoint?parameters="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"sort":"date"})),
     type: "GET",
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use JSON.stringify for GET parameters in URL like this:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "/api/endpoint?parameters="+JSON.stringify({"sort":"date"}),
           type: "GET",
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
           ...
```

Comment: -1: JSON.stringify may have an `&` which will break the request. Plus, why contentType ?

Comment: I tried this and using contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json", breaks things when you are using json.stringify(), take them out and boom, it works.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Bergi, the data is converted by `jQuery.ajax()` to request parameters.
From jQuery 1.7.2:

```
// Determine if request has content
s.hasContent = !rnoContent.test( s.type );    --> false when s.type == "GET'
```

...

```
if ( !s.hasContent ) {
    // If data is available, append data to url
    if ( s.data ) {
        s.url += ( rquery.test( s.url ) ? "&" : "?" ) + s.data;
        // #9682: remove data so that it's not used in an eventual retry
        delete s.data;
    }
```