# Can't get Javascript Object to bind to a action Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I can't seem to figure out how to get my Javascript object to bind to my model that is (as far as I can tell) just like it as far as properties go.

First the Javascript Object creation:

```
var transDetail = new Object();
transDetail.TransactionDetailID = transdetailId;
transDetail.TransactionID = "";
transDetail.Year = new Date().getFullYear();
transDetail.Volume = "";
transDetail.UnitPrice = "";
transDetail.TransferableVolume = "";
transDetail.Credits = "";
transDetail.Shares = "";
transDetail.DollarsPerShare = "";
```

It is then passed to this javascript function

```
function loadTransDetailEditCreate(d, cb, title, transactionDetail) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/TransactionDetail/LoadEditCreate',
            data: JSON.stringify(transactionDetail),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                d.html(result);
                CreateEditTransDetail(d, cb, title, transactionDetail);
                d.dialog('open');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I've verified that the year property before transmission is filled with 2015.

Now the model definition

```
public partial class TransactionDetail
{
    public int TransactionDetailID { get; set; }
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Volume { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TransferableVolume { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Credits { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Shares { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DollarsPerShare { get; set; }

}
```

And the Action definition

```
public PartialViewResult LoadEditCreate(TransactionDetail transactionDetail)
```

When I break first thing into the action all non nullable ints are set to 0 and all nullable are set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with sending the data: JSON...

You have 2 options:

1. use POST: (tried and works)

   ```
   function loadTransDetailEditCreate(d, cb, title, transactionDetail) {
   $.ajax(
       {
           type: 'post',                                      //added
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",    //added
           url: '/TransactionDetail/LoadEditCreate',
           data: JSON.stringify(transactionDetail),
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (result) {
               d.html(result);
               CreateEditTransDetail(d, cb, title, transactionDetail);
               d.dialog('open');
           }
       }
     );
   }
   ```

and decorate your controller with [HttpPost] attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult LoadEditCreate(TransactionDetail transactionDetail)
```

2. If you want to use get -  [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948233/jquery-send-json-object-using-get-method) (didn't try, should work)

Comment: Awesome thank you.  I used the first one and it worked.