# How to send multilevel JSON as GET parameter and decode to dictionary in python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary

I would like to send multilevel JSON object as GET request parameter in JavaScript. To serialize I use this:

```
json_object = {
    key_a: {
        key_aa: 1,
        key_ab: 2,
    },
    key_b: {
        key_ba: 1,
        key_bb: 2,
    },
}
var encoded_json = jQuery.param( json_object );
```

and receive:

```
key_a%5Bkey_aa%5D=1&key_a%5Bkey_ab%5D=2&key_b%5Bkey_ba%5D=1&key_b%5Bkey_bb%5D=2
```

So, next, in python I would like to decode this string:

```
print(parse_qs(json))
```

and I receive:

```
{
    'key_a[key_aa]': ['1'], 
    'key_a[key_ab]': ['2'], 
    'key_b[key_ba]': ['1'], 
    'key_b[key_bb]': ['2']
}
```

How can I transform this dictionary to form similar to input JSON object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery, send JSON object using GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948233/jquery-send-json-object-using-get-method)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I tried use parse_qs function to parse query string but the result is different than input json. Maybe I should use different function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of my question is: use JSON.stringify

```
serialized_object = JSON.stringify(object)
```

to serialize JavaScript object and next, use

```
json.loads(serialized_object)
```

in Python to get dictionary in case of POST request using.