# AngularJS RESTful params

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use the AngularJS `$http` service to parameterize a restful url?  For example:

```
var URL = '/api/countries/:countryId/states'

var getStates = function (countryId) {
    $http.get(URL, { countryId: countryId }).then();
};
```

Every combination I try ends up using a query string, which is not what I want.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216567/is-this-statement-correct-http-get-method-always-has-no-message-body. I suppose angularjs always use query string instead of body when it used the get, method if you change to post, you will see the body

Comment: @G.Deward Try using [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will be possible in the way that you describe.

In the end you'll probably just want to go with something like the following:

```
var getStates = function (countryId) {
    var URL = '/api/countries/'+countryId+'/states'
    $http.get(URL, {}).then();
};
```

Though if someone has a better solution i'd love to hear it :)

Comment: I must admit, this is rather shocking and disappointing.  How can they NOT have a RESTful URL builder in 2015?

Comment: Since @SharnWhite seems curious also, you might be interested in [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 1):

As Rathish and Tony noted, you can use $resource:

```
var URL = '/api/countries/:countryId/states'

var states = $resource(URL)

var getStates = function (countryId) {
  states.query({ countryId: countryId }).then(...)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this link will help you [AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request)

I'm on mobile right now but can post an example when I get to a computer

Answer (score 0):

$resource factory lets you build a parameterized URL
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource