# Spring boot: automatic JSON message converter for @Requestbody GET doesn't work

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

Automatic message conversion is not for the next Rest.GET. How can I use automatic JSON message conversion? I read many different solutions without solving the important issue.

Spring Boot is said to have a lot of standard message converters.

Q1: Why is the message conversion failing?

Q2: Should I really add the Jackson JSON converter to the message converter list? How?

The POJO object is:

```
public class CacheCoordinateRange {
    private double latitudeMin;
    private double latitudeMax;
    private double longitudeMin;
    private double longitudeMax;

    public CacheCoordinateRange() { }
    public CacheCoordinateRange( double latMin, double latMax, double lonMin, double lonMax) {
        this.latitudeMin = latMin;
        this.latitudeMax = latMax;
        this.longitudeMin = lonMin;
        this.longitudeMax = lonMax;
    }
    ... getters and setters
```

The Rest controller consists of:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/coordinaterange", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE )
    public List<Items> findByCoordinateRange( @RequestBody CacheCoordinateRange coordinateRange) {
return cacheRepository.findByLatitudeBetweenAndLongitudeBetween(  coordinateRange.getLatitudeMin(),
                coordinateRange.getLatitudeMax(), coordinateRange.getLongitudeMin(), coordinateRange.getLongitudeMax());
    }
```

The rest(Test)Template is:

```
CacheCoordinateRange range = new CacheCoordinateRange(  52.023456, 52.223456, -12.0234562, -12.223456);
HttpHeaders headersRange = new HttpHeaders();
headersRange.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity entityRange = new HttpEntity( range,headersRange);
ResponseEntity<SolvedCache[]> resultRange = restTestTemplate.exchange(solvedCacheRestServices + "/coordinaterange", HttpMethod.GET, entityRange, SolvedCache[].class);
        objects = responseEntity.getBody();
```

The error is:

```
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.util.List<nl.xyz.caches.Cache> nl.xyz.caches.SolvedCacheServices.findByCoordinateRange(nl.xyz.caches.CacheCoordinateRange)
```

Comment: I think the problem is likely to be that the request body is ignored because you are using a GET. Try changing your Controller and Rest client to use POST. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216567/is-this-statement-correct-http-get-method-always-has-no-message-body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that the converter isn't registered but the fact that it doesn't find a body to convert.

Change your controller to POST and your RestTemplate call to use that operation and it'll work:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/coordinaterange", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE )
public List<Items> findByCoordinateRange( @RequestBody CacheCoordinateRange coordinateRange) {
     return cacheRepository.findByLatitudeBetweenAndLongitudeBetween(  coordinateRange.getLatitudeMin(), coordinateRange.getLatitudeMax(), coordinateRange.getLongitudeMin(), coordinateRange.getLongitudeMax());
}
```

---

```
ResponseEntity<SolvedCache[]> resultRange = restTestTemplate.exchange(solvedCacheRestServices + "/coordinaterange", HttpMethod.POST, entityRange, SolvedCache[].class);
objects = responseEntity.getBody()
```

From the documentation of @RequestBody:

> Annotation indicating **a method parameter should be bound to the body
>   of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an
>   HttpMessageConverter to resolve** the method argument depending on the
>   content type of the request. Optionally, automatic validation can be
>   applied by annotating the argument with @Valid. Supported for
>   annotated handler methods in Servlet environments.

GET requests don't send a body.